# HTTP Error 404.15 The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long

Tags: asp.net

I have created a brand new web form application from Visual Studio 2013 and set the following in the web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="~/Home.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" 
        slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

When I run the project I get 404.15 error.
This is not an MVC site. 
I found a similar error that said I need to remove the "deny users" but I don't want to do that. 
I need all users to be directed to the login page if they have not authenticated. 
* [New Asp.Net MVC5 project produces an infinite loop to login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601412/new-asp-net-mvc5-project-produces-an-infinite-loop-to-login-page) * 
I also tried this but I get "This webpage has a redirect loop"
* [How to configure the web.config to allow requests of any length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636386/how-to-configure-the-web-config-to-allow-requests-of-any-length) * 

EDIT: Added more links to explain the problem.
So I found and article about login page loops. 
* http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=55 * 
So if I add a break point on the ProcessRequest I can see that there is an infinite loop calling the Login.aspx page. 
So the problem does not seem to be that the URL is too long but more likely that there is an infinite loop calling the Login.aspx page.
If I place a breakpoint on the Page_Load in side the Login.aspx page, the breakpoint never gets hit.
There must be something higher up causing the redirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I got it to work.

1. Excluded all the items under the `Account` folder except `Login.aspx`
2. Excluded `IdentityConfig` and `Startup.Auth` under the `App_Start` folder
3. Excluded `IdentityModels` under the `Models` folder
4. Excluded `Startup` under the `root` folder of the application
5. Commented out all the code under `Page_Load` and `LogIn` inside the `Login.aspx` code file
6. Commented out code with `OpenAuthProviders` in the `Login.aspx` markup
7. Added the following key to the `appSettings` section inside the `web.config` file

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
```

Comment: I had this same problem. You only need to delete the line in Startup.vb that calls Startup.Auth.vb to set authentication settings (or use startup.auth.vb to set the correct authentication settings instead of web.config).

Comment: Ian's method worked for me; I couldn't get anything else to work.

Answer (score 4):

The solution it's not completely deactivating the whole authentication system.

The problem may be caused by the access control not correctly setting Login.aspx permission when using the FriendlyUrls module. So you must force the permissions also for the Login page by it's "friendly" name. In the folder where login page it's stored, possibly will already be a web.config file that you may setup like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  ...

  <location path="Login">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  ...

</configuration>
```

Note: Take care with other pages currently in the same folder and setup accesses accordingly.