# ASP.NET single page application or MVC app and 404.15

Tags: http-status-code-404

I created a ASP.NET single page application. When I run it I get the following 404.15 error. I see the same error with an MVC application without a Web API in it also.

[image]

I commented out the ConfigureAuth code as below:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

Now I get another error which is below:

[image]

I tried to duplicate this on a different laptop, and I don't see a problem there.

Is this a directory level permission issue on this particular laptop where I created the app? Appreciate anyone can shed some light on this to fix this.

**UPDATE 11/9/2014**

I did some further debugging and found that the applications works fine with no authentication and Windows Authentication. When the authentication is forms, I see this problem happening. As you see in the IntelliTrace, the GET request is looping back to Account/Login multiple times and finally give with a 404.15 error. I added a authorization section in the web.config to allow all users to access the resources with , I still see the errors.

I see a major difference between how my laptop and the surface pro 2 behaving with the same application. In my surface pro 2, the home page is displayed and the redirect to account/login never happens. But in the laptop the redirection is happening to account/login.

There are tables in the surface pro 2 created by the asp.net identity. But in my laptop there are no tables. I believe when the application starts, there is no requirement for the tables and the control should go to the home page.

I hope anyone can provide an answer with my additional info.

[image: OWIN]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495585/http-error-404-15-the-request-filtering-module-is-configured-to-deny-a-request-w

Comment: It is not a duplication because I have not changed anything in the web.config as the other user has done.

Answer (score 0):

At first sight looking at the requestedUrl it may be the case that you are always redirecting to the same page (the login page) which creates an infinite redirect loop until the request url becomes too long: Since there is no code I can't be sure about it but I would suggest you to check your redirect url. The authentication appears just because you outcommented the ConfigureAuth method but I don't think it will solve the problem.

Comment: That is correct. It is redirecting to itself so it is going in an infinite loop. I created an MVC app without Web API, and see the same problem.

Comment: I have set up a new MVC app on my pc but everything works ok. You may try taking a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601412/new-asp-net-mvc5-project-produces-an-infinite-loop-to-login-page

Comment: I added a comment in my original post. I created a similar app in my surfacepro 2, and it is working fine. I see the problem on this laptop only. I checked that post before posting this one. That user updated the IIS config file which I don't want to do unless it is really necessary.