# get current user full name in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I have below code which works perfect but when i deploy it in IIS, it doesn't work.

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.UserDomainName + "/" + Environment.UserName);
return de.Properties["fullName"].Value.ToString();
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: what did you try?  checking logs, etc?

Comment: Are you getting any error? If not, what are you getting as a result?

Comment: I just want to get the full name of a current windows user, do I need to change anything in IIS or in my web.config?

Comment: Just follow steps in below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495585/http-error-404-15-the-request-filtering-module-is-configured-to-deny-a-request-w/28269986#28269986

Answer (score 1):

[Environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment(v=vs.110).aspx) contains information about the environment on the server, so you'll just get the username of the process your web application is running as. That's not what you want.

Instead, you should user `User.Identity.Name` to retrieve the user's username, then you can use that to obtain the user's name from AD.

Comment: Somewhat true - unless it uses windows auth + impersonation.

Comment: User.Identity.Name returns NULL

Comment: how to use windows auth and impersonation?

Comment: I added below in web.config:<authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>       but I get an error:  
HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
Most likely causes:

    system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true.

Things you can try:

    If the application supports it, disable client impersonation.
    If you are certain that it is OK to ignore this error, it can be disabled by setting system.webServer/validation@validateIntegratedModeConfiguration to false.

Comment: @MinaN In IIS, disable Anonymous Authentication, enable Windows Authentication. Don't set it to impersonate for the identity. Assuming the user is on the domain and the browser is configured correctly, you should then get the username in `User.Identity.Name`.

Comment: I removed <identity impersonate="true"/>, but still doesn't work!

Comment: @MinaN did you disable anonymous authentication in IIS and enable Windows Authentication?

Comment: yes, I get this error: HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

Comment: @MinaN what does your query string look like?

Comment: http://cmrsydw51/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FRe

Answer (score 1):

As per the .Net 4.5 recommendation you should always use ClaimsPrincipal. I am giving you a following program sample that I have just ran through console app and it has worked perfectly.

I have used an extension method here and attached to the claimsprincipal then now you can access anywhere.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var fullName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.GetFullName();
        }

        public static string GetFullName(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {

            if (!principal.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname) ||
                !principal.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName))
            {
                var dcUsername = principal.Identity;
                // get the value from dc.
                var de = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + dcUsername);

                var claims = new List<Claim> {new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, ""), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, "")};
                var id = principal.Identities.First();
                id.AddClaims(claims);
            }

            var givenName = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value;
            var surname = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value;

            return string.Format("{0} {1}", givenName, surname);
        }
```

Comment: try putting this setting  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web> under web.config

Comment: also make sure that you are using basic or windows auth.

Comment: just added  <system.web> <identity impersonate="true" /> </system.web> but when i run it i get this error:
HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
Most likely causes:

    system.web/identity@impersonate is set to true.

Things you can try:

    If the application supports it, disable client impersonation.
    If you are certain that it is OK to ignore this error, it can be disabled by setting system.webServer/validation@validateIntegratedModeConfiguration to false.

Comment: "per the .Net 4.5 recommendation" Citation needed

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.UserName` normally returns ApplicationPool user when hosted on the IIS. Try to use `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` to get the username with domain.

For example,

```
string userName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + userName);
return de.Properties["fullName"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: This does not seem to be complete; it results in an unspecified error. I think you would need to include some DirectorySearcher code to find the user and extract their data. "fullName" is not a valid property of DirectoryEntry.Properties.

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows authentication in a domain context, this solution should work in both the debugger and when deployed to IIS to get the current user's first/last name.  Add a reference to System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement first.

```
string currentUserID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

using (PrincipalContext adContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    UserPrincipal currentUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(adContext, currentUserID);
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", currentUser.GivenName, currentUser.Surname);
}
```