# VS2013 cannot debug using Anonymous Authentication. 404 when debugging using Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I turned on the feature to 'Break when an exception is Common Language Runtime Exception' using Ctrl+Alt+E in VS2013. Since then I got different errors when trying to run my project (cannot access ASP.NET Temp folder, wrong version of PageInspector, etc.), but I have found the solutions for those.

I still have a problem:
1. in the Project Properties I set Anonymous Authentication to Enabled and Windows Authentication to Disabled. Result: `"A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll"`

Additional information: Invalid file name for file monitoring ..."
2. in the Project Properties I set Anonymous Authentication to Disabled and Windows Authentication to Enabled. Result: `"404 - File or directory not found".` 
The URL looks odd as well:

> http://localhost:52016/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin.aspx%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin.aspx%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin.aspx%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin.aspx%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin.aspx%252525253
>   ... "

The URL generated is too long so I cut it off.

What could be the cause for this?

Comment: Your authentication is broken, it's stuck inside in an infinite redirect loop that keeps encoding the current url which loops and duplicates itself growing at an exponential rate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to run a .Net Web Form after publishing to the server.  First in IIS set:

Anonymous Authentication to Disabled
Windows Authentication to Enabled

This then caused the “odd” (and long) URL and 404 error.  To fix that, I had to add the “owin” key to my Web.Config:

```
<configuration>
   …
  <appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

That suggestion came from: [New Asp.Net MVC5 project produces an infinite loop to login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601412/new-asp-net-mvc5-project-produces-an-infinite-loop-to-login-page)